# React-native android back button in react-navigation

Tags: android, react-native, redux, react-navigation

Well, I have a `react-native` app with multiple screen, each screen having a top bar where a back button is situated, it's main behavior is that the app returns to the main screen when this button is pressed. What I want to do is to copy this behavior to the hardware back button (now by pressing on hardware back button the app closes), how can I do this?

**UPDATE:**

I'm using `react-navigation` and `redux`

Comment: Can you please show how you added react-navigation configuration ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can:

1. import the BackHandler from "react-native"
2. Add in the componentDidMount (componentWillMount deprecated) `BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);`
3. Implement handleBackButton like this `handleBackButton(){
       this.props.navigation.popToTop();
       return true;
   }`

popToTop goes back to the first screen in the stack.

If you are using react-navigation with Redux you should implement the popToTop as an action to dispatch.

Comment: componentWillMount is deprecated it will be removed in later version use componentDidMount instead

Comment: `return true;` prevents the default behaviour of the back button. Just what I needed, thanks!

Comment: Make sure to use an `useForceEffect` hook but not `useEffect` in functions or `cdm`/`cwun` in classes, they are all deprecated to process navigating. See [the doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-lifecycle/)

Answer (score 14):

You can do it by below example

```
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.backButtonClick = this.backButtonClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.backButtonClick);
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.backButtonClick);
  }

  backButtonClick(){
    if(this.props.navigation && this.props.navigation.goBack){
      this.props.navigation.goBack(null);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Implementation with react **Hooks** in functional components:

```
useEffect(() => {
    function handleBackButton() {
      navigation.navigate('register-phone');
      return true;
    }

    const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackButton);

    return () => backHandler.remove();
  }, [navigation]);
```

**don't forget to remove the listener on Unmount.**

based on the [react-native documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/backhandler).

Answer (score 2):

So if you are using `react-navigation` and `redux`, you can take a look at [docs - Handling the Hardware Back Button in Android](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/redux-integration.html#handling-the-hardware-back-button-in-android)

**YourComponent.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import { BackHandler } from "react-native";
import { NavigationActions } from "react-navigation";

/* your other setup code here! this is not a runnable snippet */

class ReduxNavigation extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.onBackPress);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.onBackPress);
  }

  onBackPress = () => {
    const { dispatch, nav } = this.props;
    if (nav.index === 0) {
      return false;
    }

    dispatch(NavigationActions.back());
    return true;
  };

  render() {
    /* more setup code here! this is not a runnable snippet */ 
    return <AppNavigator navigation={navigation} />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Import this package

`import { BackHandler } from "react-native";`

Bind the function in the constructor

```
this.exitApp = this.exitApp.bind(this);
```

Your back button

```
<Button transparent onPress={this.exitApp}>
    <Icon name="arrow-back" />
</Button>
```

Handle back press and close the app

```
exitApp() {
    BackHandler.exitApp()
}

// Add the listener when the page is ready
componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.exitApp);
}

// Remove the listener before removing
componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.exitApp);
}
```

The way of displaying the button might be different but this will work! If any issue write in the comments.